# Accessing relational data with dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Given the following dataframe `data`:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   Loc = rep(paste("Loc", seq(1:3), sep = "")),
                   Var  = rnorm(6))
```

we can use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::mutate` to create a new column showing the max value of `Var` for each `ID`:

```
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(MaxVar = max(Var))
```

What if we want to create another new column (we will call it `MaxVarLoc`) to show the `Loc` associated with the `MaxVar` for each `ID`?

The result would look like this:

```r
ID Loc     Var           MaxVar      MaxVarLoc

1   Loc1    -0.56047565 1.558708    LOC3
1   Loc2    -0.23017749 1.558708    LOC3    
1   Loc3    1.55870831  1.558708    LOC3    
2   Loc1    0.07050839  1.715065    LOC3    
2   Loc2    0.12928774  1.715065    LOC3    
2   Loc3    1.71506499  1.715065    LOC3    
#The result just happens to be `Loc3` in both cases here
```

How can we access relational (i.e., specify which `Loc` goes with the max value of `Var` for each `ID`) data this way in a `dplyr` framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `which.max` to return the index of `max row and select the 'Loc' based on that

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(MaxVar = max(Var), MaxVarLoc = Loc[which.max(Var)]) %>%
     ungroup
```

---

It may be also better to create the `which.max` index first and then use that to extract the 'Var' and 'Loc' elements

```
data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(imx = which.max(Var), 
          MaxVar = Var[imx], MaxVarLoc = Loc[imx], imx = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     ID Loc       Var MaxVar MaxVarLoc
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 Loc1  -0.560    1.56 Loc3     
2     1 Loc2  -0.230    1.56 Loc3     
3     1 Loc3   1.56     1.56 Loc3     
4     2 Loc1   0.0705   1.72 Loc3     
5     2 Loc2   0.129    1.72 Loc3     
6     2 Loc3   1.72     1.72 Loc3
```

---

Or may use in `across`

```
data %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(i1 = which.max(Var),
       across(Loc:Var, ~ .[i1], .names = 'Max{.col}'), i1 = NULL) %>%
    ungroup
```

---

Or we could use `slice_max` to slice the max row and do a join

```
library(stringr)
data %>%
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Var) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     rename_with(~ str_c('Max', .), -ID) %>% 
     right_join(data)
```